# How to create left menu at 100% height with twitter-bootstrap 4.2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a layout with top navbar and a left menu that collapses.

Additionally, the left menu will be hidden on medium size or smaller screen. However, the left menu will need to take the full height of the page all the time regardless of the actual size of the menu.

Here is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 mh-100 no-gutters pl-0">
  <div class="d-flex h-100">

    <div class="bg-dark h-100 mh-100 d-none d-md-block" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 22rem;">

      <ul class="list-group p-2">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href="#" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Parent - Test</a>


            <ul class="list-group collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
            </ul>

          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <main role="main" class="flex-grow-1 pl-3 h-100 mh-100">
      Here is main content....
    </main>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddler of my code https://jsfiddle.net/7fcahme8/

as you can see, the left menu is 100% height when the page is rendered. But when you click on "Parent - Test" on the left, the menu goes over the menu div which is something I want to fix. I am expecting that the left divider will expand as its content expand.

How can I make the left menu expand 100% all the time regardless of its content?

I am trying to extend the left menu divider to expand. As you can see in the screenshot below, the list-group grows more than the menu.
[image]

Comment: If you don't want it to expand to it's children you will need to have overflow-y set so that it adds a scrollbar if it's child content exceeds the height.  Not sure what you mean by "The left divider will expand as it's content expand"

Comment: I don't want to show a scrollbar. I simply want the div on the left aka menu "the dark background" to expand along with the menu so that it looks like the list-group is inside the menu. currently it goes over it

Comment: You can set a min height then and allow the element to expand.  If you set h-100 it will always be 100vh and will not expand. You have h-100 on your flex wrapper and your column so they will not expand. https://jsfiddle.net/yg4b5f6o/

Comment: I added mh-100 class but still same issue. here is the updated fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/7fcahme8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to remove the h-100 classes.  That will fix the containers to 100% of the view height.  Overflow will wrap below causing the behavior you are seeing.

If you set a min height, it will fill the are and expand as needed. Below is an example

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.side-panel{
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px); /* 100% view height - 56px (navbar height) */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid no-gutters pl-0">
  <div class="d-flex">

    <div class="bg-dark d-none d-md-block side-panel" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 22rem;">
      
      <ul class="list-group p-2">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href="#" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Parent - Test</a>
          
          
          
            <ul class="list-group collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
            </ul>
      
      
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <main role="main" class="flex-grow-1 pl-3 h-100">
      Here is main content....
    </main>
    
  </div>
</div>
```